# How to add Numpy ndarrays together?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to add multiple arrays together and I'm stuck.

For example, I have those two arrays:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2]]
```

and

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

How do I do to add them together such that the resulting array will look like this:

element from the 1st row and from the 1st column (top left) in **1st array**  +  element from the 1st row and from the 1st column  (top left) in **2nd array** = 2

So the element in the 1st row and 1st column in the **resulting array** will be 2 and so on for every element.

Thanks

Comment: simply `c=a+b`? This will element-wise add arrays `a` and `b` into a new array `c`.

Comment: seems like you have a list. import numpy as np ; np.array(a) + np.array(b)  ?

Comment: thanks, yes it does answer my question but do you have any idea how to deal with arrays that have the shape (9,9) for example? I would like to know how to "convert" any array that isn't (10,10) into a (10,10), by just adding zeroes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `.add` method for a `numpy` array:

```
sum = np.add(firstarray, secondarray)
```

Comment: thanks, any idea how to deal with arrays that have the shape (9,9) for example? I would like to know how to "convert" any array that isn't (10,10) into a (10,10), by just adding zeroes.

Comment: Check this out: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html, or ask in another question for more details.  There's really not the space in comments.